# UNITY3D - Cannot perform action after watching ad?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

The following script is supposed to reward the player when the ad has been watched:

```
public void ShowAd()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        var showOptions = new ShowOptions();
        showOptions.resultCallback += ResultCallback;
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
}

private void ResultCallback (ShowResult result) {
    if(result == ShowResult.Finished) {
        coins += 50;
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log ("No award given. Result was :: "+result);
    }
}
```

`ShowAd()` is called when a button is pressed.

The problem: I can't get the script to award the player.

Comment: Use the overload Advertisement.Show, `Advertisement.Show(zoneID, showOptions)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem:
`Advertisement.Show()` does not have a callback handler.

You need to use the other overload `Advertisement.Show(string zoneId, Advertisements.ShowOptions options)`

So you need to create a zone if you don't have one. Then replace your Show with

```
Advertisement.Show(zoneId, showOptions);
```

Comment: Where do I find zone? And what is it exactly?

Comment: It's not difficult to find an answer using Google. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/zone-id.321109/